# How to set custom validator using setValidator in Angular forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

This is the validator I have written for testing.

```
const checkValidator = (control: AbstractControl) => {
  console.log(control);
  return true;
};
```

PS: Its outside of the component class, hence const works.

Now, I am trying to set this to a control in my form.

```
this.fieldForm.get('propertiesDAMSource').setValidators([checkValidator]);
```

I get this error.

```
Argument of type '((control: AbstractControl) => boolean)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]'.
  Type '((control: AbstractControl) => boolean)[]' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
    Type '(control: AbstractControl) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.
```

Comment: Well, read the error message, and read the documentation of ValidatorFn. It's not supposed to return a boolean: https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn

Answer (score 0):

Try returning something like looks like this:

```
return { 'range': true };
```

Where 'range' is the name of your validation, instead of returning a Boolean value.